# Adding Managed Test Project to existing C++/CLI Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm in the process of working on a legacy project that was written in C++/CLI as a Windows Application with everything being compiled into a single .exe file. Since I've been tasked with writing some mathematically complex code I want to add unit testing to the solution. Upon doing so (Solution > Add > New Project > Managed Test Project) and attempting to add the project as a reference to the test project I get the following error:

[image: Visual Studio Error Message]

The main project is configured as "Pure MSIL Common Language Runtime support (/clr:pure)" and everything obvious seems to be in order, but I keep getting the error message. How can I get the solution setup to include the Unit Testing Framework?

*Google Search Phrase: Add Unit Tests to C++/CLI Project*

Comment: "Managed Unit Test" does not mean what just about anybody think it might mean.  The project type was intended to unit test *unmanaged* C++ code. For some reason being able to write the unit test code in C++/CLI was considered useful, probably because of the ability to use [attributes].  I think it can be cheated, but you'd have to edit the project file by hand to add the `<Reference>` element.  To test a C++/CLI assembly you need to use a C# or VB.NET unit test project.

Comment: @HansPassant You can also write them in C++/CLI although you seem to be limited to the Visual Studio Unit Test Framework and it's a round-about process to setup the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out and was eluded to by a commenter, you can't use the C++ Test Projects when writing tests for C++/CLR. The workaround that we found is as follows:

1. Create a new project via "[Solution] > Add > New Project > Visual C++ > CLR > CLR Empty Project"
2. Under "[Project] > Properties" set the "Configuration Type" to "Dynamical Library (.dll)"
3. Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` ours is version 14.0.23107.0
4. Add a reference to the solution project you wish to test
5. Start writing the relevant unit tests being sure to not `#include` headers from the other project, Visual Studio will resolve them for you
6. Build the solution [Ctrl+Shift+B]
7. Run your unit tests through the built in Test Explorer [Ctr+R, A]

We also verified that the tests can be run through the Unit Test Session in ReSharper 10.0.2.

Comment: Tried this, but can't get tests to show up in test explorer... Anything missing?

Comment: Okey, got it working after doing above + making a test class with _[TestClass]_ & _[TestMethod]_ attributes accordingly (declared as **public ref class MyTests**). The NUnit 2 Adapter now correctly detects the tests and I can fully test C++ & C# at the same time!

Comment: @helmesjo Can you share how you got the tests to show up in "Test Explorer"

Comment: @RohanBhosale This was quite some time ago, so can't really remember the details (or dig up the code), but did you give what I explain above a try?

Comment: @helmesjo Yes I had done the steps 1-7 but I could not see the tests in "Test Explorer" in Visual Studio. "making a test class with [TestClass] & [TestMethod] attributes accordingly (declared as public ref class MyTests)" - I have class with TestClass and TestMethod attributes as generated by the Framework but isn't right for me, hence wanted to know how you got that working.